# How to know the font family of default style in notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-custom-view, font-size, android-typeface

I create my custom view for notification and use `TextView` instead of `Action`.

The problem is: I want the `TextView` to be displayed with default style (as in default notification), but the `TextView` is displayed in different style.

[image]

So I need to know exactly the **font-size, font-family** of the default style. If I know these values, I can set them as the style of `TextView`.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:paddingLeft="8dp"` for the text **SHARE** and decrease `textSize` by *1sp* or *2sp*.

Basically, the font size used are as follows :

micro : 12sp

small : 14sp

medium : 18sp

large : 22sp

Comment: pls check my updated answer. Also, you can manipulate your textsize up and down to match your requirement.

Comment: Are you sure the font-family of custom view is the same as in the default notification?

Comment: Default notification of Android code could follow the above measurement. Not sure about custom.

Comment: I want to get the value of text color, text size and font-family of default notification. Where can I find those values?